# How to require dependencies for ruby IronWorker

Tags: ruby, ironworker

I put together a simple script to run in [iron.io](http://iron.io). I follow the steps [in this tutorial](https://github.com/iron-io/dockerworker/tree/master/ruby) but fail during testing.

```
$ docker run --rm -it -e "SLACK_API_TOKEN="xox-LALLALA"" -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker iron/ruby ruby bubbebot.rb
bubbebot.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /worker/slack-ruby-client (LoadError)
    from bubbebot.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

It's failing whether I try `require` or `relative_require`. Any idea what I need to do to vendor this dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means you are trying to use something that is not in the iron/ruby image.

To understand how to fix this, let's take a look at the Dockerfile for that image:

`FROM iron/base
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add libxml2 libxslt libevent libffi glib ncurses readline \
    openssl yaml zlib curl  mariadb-libs libpq ruby ruby-io-console \
    ruby-bigdecimal \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`

If you want to use something that is not present on that build, you'll need to add it yourself. I would suggest making your own custom Docker image. Something along the lines of this should work:

`FROM iron/ruby:2.3.1-dev
RUN apk add && apk update
RUN gem install slack --no-ri --no-rdoc
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`

Build that image and push it to Dockerhub and try running your code on that.

Comment: The real 'ah ha' is from the `--no-rdoc` installation of the slack client. Thanks for that. FWIW, I'm avoiding `-dev` to prevent the Docker image from being huge.